# Counting different rows in a group by

Tags: sql

I've got a table listing "actions", where each action has a time and a person who performed it. What I'd like is to know the count of distinct people who performed any action (doesn't matter which) each day. So my table looks like:

```
action_time         | person | action
--------------------+--------+-------
2017-05-10 10:00:00 | john   | logged on
2017-05-10 10:30:00 | paul   | logged on
2017-05-10 17:50:00 | john   | logged off
2017-05-10 18:00:00 | paul   | logged off
2017-05-11 12:00:00 | john   | read email
2017-05-12 12:00:00 | john   | read email
2017-05-13 10:00:00 | john   | read email
2017-05-13 10:30:00 | paul   | read email
2017-05-13 10:45:00 | george | read email
```

and I'd like to be able to get, as result

```
day        | count of people doing things
-----------+-----------------------------
2017-05-10 | 2 (note: john and paul each did 2 different things; don't care)
2017-05-11 | 1 (note: john only)
2017-05-12 | 1 (note: john only)
2017-05-13 | 3 (note: john, paul, and george)
```

Obviously I can `GROUP BY DATE(action_time)` (or some DB-specific version; `group by strftime('%Y-%m-%d', action_time)` in sqlite, etc), and I can also group by `person` as well... but `select date(action_time), count(person) from actions group by date(action_time)` gives *4* for the count of people doing things on the first day... i.e., it's counting the number of rows, not the number of *people* (which is 2, not 4). I don't think I understand `count()` correctly. What should I be doing here?

Comment: `count(distinct person)` is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Thank you @vkp; I'll be happy to accept that as an answer if you write it so, or I can just answer myself if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(action_time), COUNT(DISTINCT person) FROM ACTIONS GROUP BY DATE(action_time);
```